# Woocommerce admin orders page - not mobile friendly

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-admin

I have noticed that the basic Woocommerce orders list admin page does not show properly on mobile devices (iPhone 6/8/8+/MAX at least). Seems there is no separate design for small screens and the page just tries to resize to fit the screen, which creates a lot of artefacts like text being shown over checkboxes, columns missing, etc. Moreover - 
i have added, by means of code, a couple of custom columns to Woocommerce orders admin list. They show fine on desktop, but on mobile the whole screen is distorted and even sometimes flickers endlessly as if trying to redraw again and again.

I am trying to achieve the nice screen that is seen on mobile when entering WordPress admin lists. Pages, where there is the main column, which is displayed regularly and then there is a small button (class="toggle-row") which on-click (implemented in common.js) toggles "is-expanded" class to the rest of the columns which are then displayed in a list like manner.

[image][image]

First, I would like to know how to config the boilerplate Woocommerce to have the back office be mobile friendly. Then I would like to know how to fit my custom columns into that scheme as well

Comment: Which version of WooCommerce are you running? I'm looking at the orders screen on a site at the moment and it seems to drop down to a different version on mobile, no artefacts/flickering or anything like that.